# Combining mysql queries of unrelated data when related point is a substring()

Tags: mysql

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how to combine these queries together.

Here is my db setup:

Table 1:

```
querylog - log of all api calls application makes
    - id (AI)
    - url (VARCHAR)
    - when (DATETIME)
```

Table 2:

```
trades - data returned from api calls
    - tid (trade ID, unique)
    - price
    - date (datetime) - when trade occured, not when inserted
    - etc
```

I am trying to get a count of records added in the last hour.

I can use this sql statement to get the first trade TID added in the last hour (pre-modified url is in the form: `https://API_INFO_HERE/trades?id=TID_HERE`)

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(url,50, 50) as oldest from querylog where url like 'https://API_INFO_HERE/trades?%' and `when`>= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR) ORDER BY `querylog`.`when` DESC LIMIT 1
```

Then to get the count all i need is:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `trades` where tid > VALUE_FROM_PREVIOUS_QUERY
```

If anyone could help me combine the queries I would be very appreciative!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should do something like this:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `trades`
WHERE tid > (SELECT SUBSTRING(url,50, 50) as oldest from querylog where url like 'https://API_INFO_HERE/trades?%' and `when`>= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR) ORDER BY `querylog`.`when` DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Keep in mind though, that it may be slow, if there's no index on substring(url,50,50).
You should probably consider logging request time in trades table as well or in contrary add appropriate index on querylog, to speed things up.

Comment: Works perfectly (except DESC should be ASC, that was my mistake in the first post), when it comes to mysql the answer always seems to be easier than it first appears!